# Can't show ip in different subnet at ipmessenger

Tags: windows, lan, subnet, ipmsg

I use IPMessenger to chat on LAN. It can show all IPs in the same subnet. For IPs in another subnet it does not show. How to setup my IPMESSENGER so I can chat to all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add each IP in `Settings` -> `Broadcast setup for wide area network`.